# VUgen: Recording trivial RMI interaction records invalid script?

Tags: java, load-testing, loadrunner

After recording just the appearance of the logon window of our Java app in LR/VUgen 9.51 using the RMI protocol, the resulting script replays with a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. The code fragment looks like this:

```
_hashtable2 = new Hashtable();
_object_array3 = ((java.util.Collection)_hashtable2.values()).toArray();
_hashtable2.put("sessionId",(java.lang.String)_object_array3[0]); //yields exception!
_boolean1 = _mopsconstantserverif1.psi_requiresHostCommunication((java.util.Hashtable)_hashtable2, (java.util.Vector)null);
```

Of course generating an empty hashtable, converting it to an array, and referencing its first array element **must** yield an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, right? But why does LR generate this kind of code at all? Is this a bug, or what am I doing wrong? I have never seen problems like this one when using RMI and LoadRunner.

Since the cause of the playback error is quite obvious and independent of the remainder of the recorded code (i.e. limited to the four statements shown), I try to ask without showing the whole script...

Comment: Wow, either my question is stupid, or pointless, or hits a 100% knowledge gap...I still believe in the third option.

Comment: Come on guys, eat my reputation points by throwing answers at me...please!!!

Comment: WHY Don't you ask this question directly to people who wrote LOADRUNNER then, inspite of ...

Comment: @SVM: Good point. Because they do not know. I did. Problem is they want me to sent them the app´s source, which I do not have access to. (This probably narrows my chances of getting good answers, agree, but it might be other folks have seen similar symptoms, and found a workaround.)

Comment: if you had previously been able to record/replay scripts with similar BP with LR - take a look at those scripts - did they have anything similar (building a hashtable + filling it + using it)? What script would be if you try recording the same BP with previous version of LR that worked for you? Does your script contain any data that might be used to populate "SessionId" manually?

Comment: They indeed look similar. Exactly what is missing here is present in there: Assignments of values to the array. Unfortunately, the session ID handling was changed in the app, so I cannot compare 1:1. I think the new release of the app does something that is not standard RMI behavior from LR's perspective. I meanwhile believe that if I do not get access to the sources, I won't be able to cover the app. Other people using different tools to record stuff and generate Java source code for monitoring scripts have exactly the same problem, which kind of indicates that it is not an LR problem :(

Comment: RMI is rarely used by those who do use LoadRunner. I suggest asking this over at qaforums.com, the loadrunner yahoo group, google group or the performance experts group on linkedin. qaforums would be my first choice. I had a similar problem with Facilita Forecast but thankfully I could get away with just removing the offending lines.

Comment: Thanks Gaz. After locating stackoverflow, I try to avoid that "diversity" in searching whenever I can. But yes, it'll be worth a try.

Comment: There is nothing here to suggest that it has anything do with [tag:rmi].

Answer (score -1):

Ahh, RMI, the bane of my existence.   I so dislike the RMI/Java combination in LoadRunner I do as much RMI work in Winsock as I can.  You might consider the use of Winsock as a plan B option to avoid the Java issues you are experiencing today as Winsock is a straight C virtual user type.   The use of a Windows sockets virtual user avoids the complications of the dark magic of Java and LoadRunner, plus it's lighter weight on the resource front and it's faster as a result.   And, I am just a glutton for punishment on the Winsock front plus it keeps the C skills razor sharp!

Comment: Will check out WinSock with that app too, and take a look at LR11's RMI support. If the WinSock suggestion wins, I'll accept this answer if you clean up the grammar a bit.

Comment: I don't believe the RMI support has changed much with LoadRunner 11.   At this point RMI is a market historical protocol, with very low levels of volatility in it's evolution - In essence the interface is rock stable and has been so for the better part of a half a decade or more.   My best guess is that they simply ported the common code to the new release and validated the work actions against several newer releases of Java on newer operating systems, but that is about all I would expect.

Comment: How is this relevant? What part of the failure relates to RMI, and why? Evidence please.

Comment: The "dark magic: int is case was referring to the mind numbing matrix of version of LoadRunner, versions of Java, 32-bit or 64-bit variants, plus OS variants.   The use of Winsock is far simpler, simply pass a buffer and receive a buffer.  Completely avoids the complications of versions of OS, guest OS, etc...